# Finding a specific nibble in an integer

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

How would I go about finding a nibble in an integer using bitwise operations?

I need to extract a given nibble, specifically.

The method looks something like this

```
private int nibbleExtract(int x, int whichNibbleToGet)
```

and example on what this method would return

`nibbleExtract(0xFF254545, 7); // => 0xF`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by shifting the number by 4 times the nibble index, and masking with `0xF`:

```
int nibbleIndex = 7;
int data = 0xFF254545;
int nibble = (data >> 4*nibbleIndex) & 0xF;
```

> How would you do this without multiplication?

Like this:

```
int nibble = (data >> (nibbleIndex << 2)) & 0xF;
```

Modern optimizers will convert `4*x` to `x << 2` for you, so the two alternatives usually turn out to give you the same performance (while the first one is of course more readable).

Comment: How would you do this without multiplication?